# $\lim\limits_{N \to +\infty} \sqrt{N+1} \log\left (1+\frac{x}{N+1}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to compute the limit

$$
\lim\limits_{N \to +\infty} \sqrt{N+1} \log \left(1+\frac{x}{N+1}\right)
$$
where $x \ge 0$ is fixed. I tried to see the previous as

$$
\log \lim\limits_{N \to +\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{N+1}\right)^{\sqrt{N+1}}
$$
and to change variable, but it doesn't work. Intuitively, this limit is 0, but I have no clue on how to solve it. Can you help me?

Comment: $$\log (1 + t) = 1 + t + O(t^2)$$

Comment: Letting $M=N+1$ will at least reduce the noise in your equation :)

Comment: $$\log (1 + t) = {\color{red}0} + t + O(t^2)$$

Answer (score 3):

The "+1" doesn't matter.

For large $N$ and fixed $x$

$\sqrt{N} \log (1+\frac{x}{N})
=\sqrt{N} (\frac{x}{N}+O((\frac{x}{N})^2))
=\frac{x}{\sqrt{N}}+O(\frac{1}{N^{3/2}})
\to 0
$.

This holds with
$N^{c}$
(instead of $\sqrt{N}$)
for all
$0 < c < 1$.

If
$c=1$,
we have
$N \log (1+\frac{x}{N})
=N (\frac{x}{N}+O((\frac{x}{N}))^2)
=x+O(\frac{1}{N})
\to x
$.

Answer (score 2):

This one is easy and an immediate consequence of the fundamental inequality satisfied by $\log$ function: $$\log x\leq x-1,x>0\tag{1}$$ For the current question we have $x\geq 0$ and hence $$0\leq \sqrt{N+1}\log\left(1+\frac{x}{N+1}\right) \leq \frac{x} {\sqrt{N+1}}$$ and the result follows via Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to use **L' Hospital**:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n+1})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2(n+1)^{5/2}}{(n+1+x)(n+1)^2} \to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's pose $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}}$. Then, when $N$ goes to $+\infty$, then $z$ goes to $0$. You can rewrite your limit as follows:

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z} \log\left(1 + xz^2\right).$$

It is well known that:

$$\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\log\left(1 + a\right)}{a} = 1.$$

Starting from this, we can rewrite the original limit as follows:

$$\lim_{z \to 0} xz \left(\frac{\log\left(1 + xz^2\right)}{xz^2}\right) = 0 \cdot 1 = 0.$$

The idea here is that "$a = xz^2$", since both goes to $0$...

---

If the limit was

$$\lim\limits_{N \to +\infty} (N+1) \log \left(1+\frac{x}{N+1}\right),$$

then, passing to $z$, we get:

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z^2} \log\left(1 + xz^2\right),$$

or equivalently

$$\lim_{z \to 0} x \left(\frac{\log\left(1 + xz^2\right)}{xz^2}\right) = x \cdot 1 = x.$$

Comment: Good rephrasing.

Comment: @martycohen Good answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}\ln(1+\frac x{n+1})) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(1+\frac x{n+1})}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac x{n+1})^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}. $$

Can you finish from here?

Answer (score -1):

hint: use taylor expansion for the Log term

Comment: Why the down votes to this answer?  The OP asked for  clue; this is a fine clue, without huffing and puffing.